# System images do not show up in SDK Manager

Tags: android-sdk, avd-manager

When I try to create a new AVD, I get the error that there is no system image available. A quick search on the internet tells me that I should download it via the SDK manager, but no system images are showing up in the list.

As well, I get an error that it cannot fetch information from two .xml files. Does this have anything to do with the system images?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There may be the proxy problem. Go to the option under tools and enter the Http proxy and port no.

Comment: as he is able to access other xml files within the sdk manager this is most liekly not his problem.

Comment: This answer did resolve the same problem on my computer. The "Http proxy" setting in Android Studio was set as "Auto-detect proxy settings". I have changed this setting to "Manual proxy configuration" and entered "Host name" and "Port number". After that the list of system images has been successfully loaded.